# Three.js: Calling lookAt() method causes mesh to disappear

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to use the three.js lookAt() method on a meshes (from CylinderBufferGeometry) so that it is oriented toward a point, but when I use the .lookAt() method, it causes the mesh to disappear from view.

The cylinder shows up fine if I comment out the .lookAt() method. I'm using a THREE.PerspectiveCamera and the THREE.WebGLRenderer incase that could have anything to do with the issue.

```
// Build cylinder
var cylinderRadius = 0.15
var cylinderHeight = 20

var geometry = new THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry(cylinderRadius, cylinderRadius, cylinderHeight);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff});
var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

// Point the cylinder up
cylinder.geometry.rotateX( Math.PI / 2);
cylinder.geometry.translate(0,0, cylinderHeight/2 );

// Move cylinder to position
cylinder.position.x = 10;
cylinder.position.y = 10;

// Look at point
cylinder.lookAt(0,0,15);  // <-- ISSUE OCCURS HERE

scene.add(cylinder);

render();
```

Comment: `cylinder.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 15 ) );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use cylinder.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,15)); instead of cylinder.lookAt(0,0,15);